# do not execute the next command if find is empty (xargs --no-run-if-empty)

Tags: shell

How can I prevent the execution of "if/else condition" if the xargs is no run ?

```
find $SRC -type f -name 'file_*' | xargs --no-run-if-empty rm -v

if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
  echo "removed"
else
  echo "failed to remove"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `if/else` inside a shell run inside `xargs`:

```
xargs sh -c '
    if [ "$#" = 0 ]; then
         echo "no files to remove"
    elif rm -v "$@"; then
        echo "removed"
    else
        echo "failed to remove"
    fi ' --
```

Use a separate entity like a file to transfer the information of no input.

```
rm -f /tmp/tempfile

... |
xargs sh -c '
   if [ "$#" = 0 ]; then
        echo "no files to remove" > /tmp/tempfile
   fi
   rm -v "$@" ' --

# or with a separate part in a pipeline that
#   tries to read one line of input
... |
{
  if ! IFS= read -r l; then
     echo "no files to remove" > /tmp/tempfile
  else
     printf "%s\n" "$l"
     cat
  fi
} | xargs --no-run-if-empty rm -v 


ret=$?

if [ -e /tmp/tempfile ]; then
     if [ "$ret" -eq 0 ] ; then
          echo "removed"
     else
         echo "failed to remove"
     fi
fi
```

Use the property of [GNU xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) to return 124 in case of 255 exit status.

```
... |
xargs sh -c '
   if [ "$#" = 0 ]; then
        exit 255
   fi
   rm -v "$@" ' --

ret=$?

if [ "$ret" -ne 124 ]; then
     if [ "$ret" -eq 0 ] ; then
          echo "removed"
     else
         echo "failed to remove"
     fi
fi
```

Comment: is it possible to echo all of the removed files (file_*) with this nested conditions?
(please let me know if i should create a new question for this)

Comment: Add `printf "%s\n" "$@"` somewhere in the subshell.